# Saving Document directly as a value of id in Spring-data-Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I want to save a JSON object as a Document in Couchbase. The id of this document is supposed to be retrieved from this JSON object and the value is supposed to be this JSON object itself. Since this JSON is too complex, I haven't mapped it directly to any POJO class, but I have created a Simple POJO, which has two fields as shown below

```
@Document
public class SimplePojo{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field()
    private String complexJsonString;//the JSON string is stored in this variable
}
```

I also have a SimplePojoRepository as shown below

```
@Component
public interface SimplePojoRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<SimplePojo, String>{
}
```

Now, I am setting the id and complexJsonString manually before calling the save method:-

```
 SimplePojo myObj= new SimplePojo();
 myObj.setId(myKey);
 myObj.setComplexJsonString(jsonString);
 simplePojoRepository.save(myObj);
```

This is working fine, but it is saving the Document in below format

```
myKey: {
  complexJsonString : {//the original json Object here}
}
```

but I don't want this, I want to save it like this:-

```
myKey : {//the original json Object here}
```

So, to make it clear, **I don't want to save my JSON object as a value of `complexJsonString` but rather, directly as a value of the `myKey` .** Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the complexJsonString as a nested entity within your main object, you have to transform it in a Pojo:

```
myObj.setSomeEntity(new SomeEntity())
```

You can easily transform your JSON-encoded String to object using jackson's ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue( jsonString, SomeEntity.class);
```

However, if you don't have control on the structure of this json, you will need to use the standard Java SDK instead of the Spring Data One:

```
JsonObject obj = JsonObject.create().put(this.documentTypeName, this.documentValue)
                    .put("attrNam1", "attrValue1")
                    .put("attrNam2", "attrValue2")

JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.create(session.getId(), maxExpirationTime, obj);
bucket.upsert(doc)
```

In the case above, you will need to parse your JSON-encoded string using some lib (ex: gson/jackson) and then convert it to a couchbase JsonDocument.

Lastly, you could also leave your code as it is and use the N1QL function `DECODE_JSON()` whenever you need to access some property of this json string.

ex:

```
SELECT
    i.itemName as itemName,
    SUM(i.quantity) AS totalQuantity
FROM sessionstore s
UNNEST DECODE_JSON(s.sessionCart).shoppingCart.items i
WHERE s.sessionCart IS NOT MISSING
GROUP BY i.itemName
ORDER BY SUM(i.quantity) DESC
LIMIT 10
```